# How to use Express request method post

Tags: express, request

I have a lot of problems with my first use of Express's request method.
I want to receive text/html.

However, if you apply it as below, an error occurs.

```
const api_request = require('request'); 
let test = {
    "testValue" : "notepad"
}
api_request.post({ 
    url :'https://url', 
    body : test,
    json : true,
    headers: {'Content-Type' : 'text/html;charset=utf-8'},
},function(err, res, body){
    if(err){
        console.log('err',err);
    }
    console.log('body',body);
})
```

**error**

```
body <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.77 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-    family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-    family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 400 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.77</h3></body></html>
```

How should I approach it?
Thank you for your kind answer.

Comment: see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#forms

Comment: Do you know that the `request()` library is deprecated and should not be used for new projects?  There's a list of alternatives [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).

Comment: The response you're getting back says "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.".  You are apparently not sending an appropriate request to this server.  Since you don't disclose what site you're trying to reach, there's nothing we can do to help you construct the proper request.  You will have to figure that out yourself or disclose what a legal request would look like.